# Interface change and SOLID principles

Tags: solid-principles

I am confused about the concept of SOLID principles.

As an example: I develop an application that uses properties. According to SOLID, I should have an abstraction that accesses the properties of the application, so I use an interface to set and get a property's value — behind the interface could be a database, a file... anything.

What will happen if there is a new need to also get a description of a property? If the interface changes, a lot of changes will follow. How can one design an interface that doesn't change even if the needs change?

Comment: If the interface needs to expose another property, the interface will likely need to change.  The reason for the abstraction is so the implementation delivering the interface can change without effecting client code.  If the client code needs a new property, this is a change to the abstraction, so you can: 1) change the interface; 2) create a new interface.  Which you chose depends on why you are making the change, and what else using the current interface.

Comment: To add to the comment from @dbugger, _create a new interface_ could mean extending the existing interface. That approach would align with the I in SOLID.

Comment: Grammar changes mainly.